# How to find the transformed point3d coordinates of a transformed ModelVisual3D

Tags: .net, wpf, 3d, transform

I want to click on a model in a Viewport3D and find the 3D coordinates of a model. I want the transformed coordinates.

Suppose you have this in a Viewport3D:

```
<ModelVisual3D x:Name="yellowTriangle">
 <ModelVisual3D.Content>
  <GeometryModel3D>
   <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
    <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,0,0 0,1,0 1,0,0" TriangleIndices="0,2,1"/>
   </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
   <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
    <Transform3DGroup>
     <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="10" OffsetY="20" OffsetZ="-10"/>
     <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1.5" ScaleZ="1"/>
     <RotateTransform3D>
      <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
       <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="20" Axis="1 0 0"/>
      </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
     </RotateTransform3D>
     <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="0"/>
    </Transform3DGroup>
   </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
   <GeometryModel3D.Material>
    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Yellow"/>
   </GeometryModel3D.Material>
  </GeometryModel3D>
 </ModelVisual3D.Content>
```

Using a VisualTreehelper.HitTest I can get to the MeshGeometry3D and the Point3D Positions. However, I can only get the original Point3D's : -1,0,0 etc. How do I get the transformed Point3D's ?

According to [Ericsink's autozoom](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/A_AutoZoom.html) remarks I should:

> walk up the visual tree from every MeshGeometry3D and stop to apply every Transform >object it finds along the way

But I don't succeed. Anyone has a way to reach to the ModelVisual3D of a MeshGeometry3D ?

Or a faster way to reach those transformed Point3D's ?

---

Adding the hittest code:

```
    private void Viewport3D_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult rayMeshResult = (RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult)
            VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(mainViewport, e.GetPosition(mainViewport));

        if (rayMeshResult.MeshHit is MeshGeometry3D)
        {
            MeshGeometry3D mesh = (MeshGeometry3D)rayMeshResult.MeshHit;
            foreach (Point3D point3d in mesh.Positions)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("original point: " + point3d.ToString());
                Point3D p = new Point3D();
                // Using the Modelhit now because the meshhit doesn't contain a transform
                Transform3D trans = rayMeshResult.ModelHit.Transform;
                p = trans.Transform(point3d);
                MessageBox.Show("transformed point: " + p.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

I cleaned up my hittest code and it works with the "yellowTriangle" above. The problem only occurs with my derived Rectangle3D code based on Daniel Lehenbauer's extending Visual3d: "http://blogs.msdn.com/danlehen/archive/2005/10/16/481597.aspx"

Something like this doesn't give me the correct transformations:

```
        <primitive3D:Rectangle3D>
            <primitive3D:Rectangle3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Green"/>
            </primitive3D:Rectangle3D.Material>
            <primitive3D:Rectangle3D.Transform>
                <Transform3DGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="0"/>
                    <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" ScaleZ="10"/>
                    <RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                            <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="30" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                        </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    </RotateTransform3D>
                    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0" OffsetY="0" OffsetZ="0"/>
                </Transform3DGroup>
            </primitive3D:Rectangle3D.Transform>

        </primitive3D:Rectangle3D>
```

I guess my derived rectangle3D should have a DependencyProperty for the Transformations ?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you get what you want - [Transform3DGroup.Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.transform3dgroup.transform.aspx)

It will allow you to transform a point or set of points using the TransformGroups transformation, where in your case the Transform3DGroup to use is contained in the GeometryModel3D.Transform property.

Comment: Well I tried the Modelhit.Tranform property but that always gives me this matrix:
    1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0
    0 0 0 1

casting the Transform property to a Transform3DGroup gives Null

Comment: Can you post your HitTest code and the callback you use to process the result?

Answer (score 0):

When doing hitTesting, you can find the Transformation matrix of a ModelVisual3D in the

```
Transform3D transformOnModelVisual3D = rayMeshResult.VisualHit.Transform;
```

This corresponds with Transforms set on:

```
<ModelVisual3D x:Name="yellowTriangle">
 <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
  <RotateTransform3D>
    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
     <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="60" Axis="0 1 0"/>
    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
  </RotateTransform3D>
 </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
....
</ModelVisual3D>
```

And another transform can be found in

```
Transform3D transformOnGeometryModel3D = rayMeshResult.ModelHit.Transform;
```

corresponding with:
    ...

```
<ModelVisual3D.Content>
 <GeometryModel3D>
  <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
   <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,0,0 0,1,0 1,0,0" TriangleIndices="0,2,1"/>
  </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
  <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
   <Transform3DGroup>
    <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="-2" OffsetY="1" OffsetZ="-1"/>
   </Transform3DGroup>
  </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
 </GeometryModel3D>
</ModelVisual3D.Content>
```